# Using $location.url() inside a directive not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a directive and inside it, I used the `$location.url()` but it seems not working, and I think I need to inject something on my app but I don't know where to inject it. By the way I'm new to `angularJS.` Here's my code:

```
app.controller('CVSRRC-CTRL', function($scope,$http,$location){

        // some codes here

});
app.directive('cvsrrc', [function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('dblclick', function(){
            $location.url("admin");
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

It doesn't work, but I tried to replace the `$location.url("admin");`  to `alert(1)`  It works properly.  And when I checked the console it says that `$location is undefined`. What should I do  ?

Comment: Why not use the `ng-dblclick` directive? See [AngularJS ng-dblclick Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick).

Comment: Yes, but I just want to try that one above :) @georgeawg

Comment: Please inject $location into directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject $location as a dependency and you need to call $apply so that angular will trigger a digest cycle:

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template: '<div cvsrrc class="box">  </div>'       
    })
    .when("/admin", {
        template : "ADMIN"
    })
  }])
  .directive('cvsrrc',  ['$location', function($location){
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.bind('dblclick', function(){
              scope.$apply(function(){
                $location.path("/admin");
              });
            });
          }
        }
  }]);
```

```css
.box{
  height:100px; 
  width:100px; 
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <ng-view>
    
  </ng-view>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But it is still not working for me. `<img src=".." cvsrrc />`

Comment: Missed that the location update was happening out of digest cycle, in addition to $location not being injected - @georgeawg's answer has excellent info. My answer has been updated with a simple functional example of routes being defined, and the directive working with them :)

Answer (score 2):

When an event comes from outside the AngularJS framework, the framework needs to have a digest cycle initiated with $apply.

[image]

```
app.controller('CVSRRC-CTRL', function($scope,$http,$location){
    // some codes here
});
app.directive('cvsrrc', ['$location', function($location){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('dblclick', function(){
            $location.url("admin");
            scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

> ### Using `$location` outside of the scope life-cycle
>
> `$location` knows about AngularJS's [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) life-cycle. When a URL changes in the browser it updates the `$location` and calls `$apply` so that all [$watchers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) / [$observers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) are notified. When you change the $location inside the `$digest` phase everything is ok; `$location` will propagate this change into browser and will notify all the [$watchers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) / [$observers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe). When you want to change the `$location` from outside AngularJS (for example, through a DOM Event or during testing) - you must call `$apply` to propagate the changes.
>
> [-- AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location Outside Scope Life-Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#using-location-outside-of-the-scope-life-cycle)